# Get menu item of a content type

Tags: routes, 8, entities

Is it possible to get the menu item of a certain content type through the API?

The idea is to improve [Markus Orenstrat solution](https://www.dunix-data.de/blog/drupal_8_set_menu_active_trail_based_on_type_of_currently_viewed_node) to set the active trail based on the content type. As it stands it requires hardcoding the `menu_tree` id in the service.

```
 if ($bundle == 'blog') {
   $plugin_id = 'menu_link_content:a00a209d-075e-46a2-b200-e2d439d92228b';
 }
```

I figured this could be avoided since the administration area allows to assign a menu item to a content type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's stored in the third party settings of the node type.

```
$type = NodeType::load('article');
$type->getThirdPartySetting('menu_ui', 'parent')
```

See also menu_ui_get_menu_link_defaults().